# dynamically increasing height of div in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to increase the height of the div tag on click of button. Every time a user clicks a button it should increase the height of that particular div tag, say by 200px or so..

## HTML

```
      <div id="controls">
         <input type="button" onclick="incHeight()" id="btn" name="btn">
      </div>
      <div id="container" style="min-height:250px;"> &nbsp;</div>
```

The below script works properly

## Javascript

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function incHeight()
        {
          document.getElementById("container").style.height = 250+'px';

        }
      </script>
```

But I want to do something like this, which is not working. The problem I think is the 'px' portion in the value. Anybody have any idea how to extract the INT portion of the value...

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function incHeight()
        {
          document.getElementById("container").style.height += 250;     
        }
      </script>
```

The problem is how do I get the '250' portion of the height value neglecting the 'px' in javascript..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
function incHeight() {
    var el = document.getElementById("container");
    var height = el.offsetHeight;
    var newHeight = height + 200;
    el.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
}
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C2cTL/)

Answer (score 3):

Try something like

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
container.style.height = (container.offsetHeight + 250) + "px";
```

In case `offsetHeight` is not working, try parsing the `style.height` for its numeric value instead.

```
var currentHeight = (container.style.height) ? (parseInt(container.style.height.match(/[0-9]+/)[0]) : container.offsetHeight;
```

Also, simply `parseInt(container.style.height)` might work

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

```
getElementById('container').setAttribute("style","height:500px");
```

**or**

```
function resize(element) {
  var height = 0;
  var body = window.document.body;
  if (window.innerHeight) {
      height = window.innerHeight;
  } else if (body.parentElement.clientHeight) {
      height = body.parentElement.clientHeight;
  } else if (body && body.clientHeight) {
      height = body.clientHeight;
  }
  element.style.height = ((height - element.offsetTop) + "px");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to only keep the numbers in the string:

```
var style = document.getElementById("container").style;
style.height = style.height.replace( /^\D+/g, '') + 'px';
```